pd.read_excel( , engine = "pyxlsb") is reading string columns as blank
I am using pd.read_excel(file, engine='pyxlsb') to read a .xlxb file.
The file looks like this



Name
Marks




A
25


B
27



But, when I read it in pandas the datafranme is like



nan
nan




nan
25


nan
27



So, all the strings are not read and replaced with blanks?
I tried using pd.read_excel(file, engine='calamine')

Were the cells filled programmatically, do they hold functions returning strings?

engine xlsb / file xlxb?
